# syntax error in SQL Update statement

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm getting a syntax error in my UPDATE statement, but I'm not sure where exactly it is. Here's my code:

```
    strSelected = "UPDATE CFRRR SET assignedby = " & Me.cmbassignedby.Column(1) & ", assignedto = " & _
                                  Me.cmbassignedto.Column(2) & ", Dateassigned = " & Now() & ", actiondate = " & _
                                  Now() & ", Workername = " & Me.cmbassignedto.Column(2) & ", WorkerID = " & _
                                  Me.cmbassignedto.Column(1) & " WHERE CFRRRID In ( " & strSelected & " );"
CurrentDb.Execute strSelected
```

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because of the `Now()` function, which also prints the current time (seperated with a space) - hence the syntax error. Try to surround them with single quotation marks.

You can also print out the SQL Statement
`Debug.Print strSelected` to see what you have concatenated...

Comment: What if you surround the date values with `#` ? Something like  `... Dateassigned = #" & Now() & "#, action..."`

Comment: So the string you are trying to construct has to be a valid sql query. This means text values should be surounded by single quotation marks, the date values should be surounded by #. Did you check if all variables contain values? The best way to find out is to `Debug.Print` the `strSelected` variable to see the resulting query. Use `Ctrl + G` to show the Immediate Window inside the VBA Editor.

Comment: I'm not getting anything when I put `Debug.Print strSelected` in the immediate window.

Comment: You have to insert the `Debug.Print` statement right before `CurrentDb.Execute strSelected` and set a breakpoint on CurrentDb.Execute. When you execute your code switch to the Immediate Window and examine the resulting string...

Comment: So theses are the results of the code in the immediate window. I don't see a problem though: `UPDATE CFRRR SET CFRRR.assignedby = Smith, Jane, CFRRR.assignedto = Smith, John, CFRRR.Dateassigned = 5/3/2015 11:26:32 AM, CFRRR.actiondate = 5/3/2015 11:26:32 AM, CFRRR.Workername = Smith, John, CFRRR.WorkerID = 6 WHERE CFRRRID In ( 84 );`

Comment: As said... there are many problems with this statement. Text values should be surrounded by single quotation marks... the resulting string should look like `UPDATE CFRRR SET CFRRR.assignedby = 'Smith, Jane', CFRRR.assignedto = 'Smith, John', CFRRR.Dateassigned = #5/3/2015 11:26:32#, CFRRR.actiondate = #5/3/2015 11:26:32#, CFRRR.Workername = 'Smith, John', CFRRR.WorkerID = 6 WHERE CFRRRID In ( 84 );`